# Why can't I get Google Fonts to work?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

So I've tried linking in the head of the html page and using the @import in my css file, but the font I'm trying to use still will not load. I also checked to make sure I'm not running any plugin that could be causing the problem, so I'm really not sure what to do. If anyone could help me solve this that would be wonderful.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylsheet" href="anagram.css">
</head>
<body>
  <p>Look here!</p>
</body>
</html>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);

p {
font-family:'Tangerine';
font-size:48px;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `rel="stylesheet"`?

Comment: try to put quote like `@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine');`

Comment: yeah agree with @WaleedKhan, on second look i see you have typo mistake here <link type="text/css" rel="stylsheet" href="anagram.css">, should be `rel="stylesheet"` and

Comment: @WaleedKhan, this is not enough `Perhaps you meant rel="stylesheet"?` even you not pointing where he made mistake

Comment: Oh my god, it was a typo lol

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I just couldn't see it before

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The CSS is correct, but you can't just tack raw CSS onto the HTML like that. Move it into a `<style>` tag, inside the `<head>` or `<body>`.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);

          p {
            font-family:'Tangerine';
            font-size:48px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Look here!</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't place CSS randomly in your HTML file like that. It needs to be in a `<style>` tag, or an external stylesheet. Move your CSS into a `<style>` tag, which should be inside the `<head>`, assuming you're not over-riding an existing "global" stylesheet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website... whatever</title>
    <style>
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);
    
        p { font-family: 'Tangerine'; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>My font is called Tangerine</p>
</body>
</html>
```

...or, what I find easier when using Google Fonts is to link the font's stylesheet, and then just reference it in my stylesheet. When using Google Fonts, this is the default method.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website... whatever</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        p {
            font-family: 'Tangerine';
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Tangerine';
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 150%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I'm thick and large.</h1>
    <p>I'm thin and small.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use this method, make sure to include it *before* your own CSS that will make use of the font.

The above also shows you how to import multiple weights/styles of a font, and how to use them in your CSS. In this example, paragraph use the lighter font weight, while `<h1>` headings use the heavier (thicker) weight, also at a larger size.

You can't just choose arbitrary weights, however. Tangerine for example only has two weights: 400 and 700, and I've imported both for this example. Only import those you are going to use though, as importing too many fonts/styles will increase load times unnecessarily.

Hope this helps.